# Interpolating 3D data (irregular vertical mesh) to regular vertical mesh. Optimization loops

Tags: python, optimization, loops, interpolation

I'm working with a 3D field. The horizontal mesh is irregular and also the vertical mesh is irregular and differs from one node to another one in the horizontal grid (due to sigma vertical coordinates).

I want to interpolate this data on a regular vertical coordinates and right now the only way I found is to loop over each horizontal point to then do a simple 1D vertical interpolation. This is easy to implement (see below a simple example) but totally non-efficient (10 min to interpolate one time step in my original case and I have more than 10 000 time steps to post-proceed)
    #! /usr/bin/python
    import numpy as np
    from scipy import interpolate

```
## Horizontal mesh
x = range(0,300); y = range(0,200)
[X,Y] = np.meshgrid(x,y)

## Input 
z1   = np.array([0.,5.,10.,20.,50.,100.,200.,500.,1000.])
Z_in = np.zeros((z1.shape[0],X.shape[0],X.shape[1]))
for i in range(0,X.shape[0]):
  for j in range(0,X.shape[1]):
     Z_in[:,i,j]  = z1[:]
Z_in = Z_in+np.random.randint(-2,2,size=(z1.shape[0],X.shape[0],X.shape[1]))
var_in = np.random.randint(-10,10,size=(z1.shape[0],X.shape[0],X.shape[1]))

## Output
zout = np.array([0.,2.5,5.,7.5,10.,15.,20.,35.,50.,75.,100.,150.,200.,500.,1000.])
var_out = np.zeros((zout.shape[0],X.shape[0],X.shape[1]))

##Interpolation
for i in range(0,X.shape[0]):
   for j in range(0,X.shape[1]):
      var_out[:,i,j] = interpolate.interp1d(Z_in[:,i,j],var_in[:,i,j],bounds_error=False,fill_value=np.nan)(zout)
```

If my initial vertical mesh was regular in each point, it would be easy according to this previous post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755871/interpolating-a-3d-array-in-python-how-to-avoid-for-loops) but in my case I cannot find an easy solution. I tried to use a mapping with a function:

```
def interp_perso(Z_in,var_in,zout): return interpolate.interp1d(Z_in[:],var_in[:],bounds_error=False,fill_value=np.nan)(zout)

Zout =  np.zeros((X.shape[0],X.shape[1]))
for l in range(0,zout.shape[0]):
   Zout[:,:] = zout[l]
   var_out[l] = map(interp_perso,Z_in,var_in,Zout)
```

but I still arrived to the interp1d error: "ValueError: the x array must have exactly one dimension." Do you know any other way to implement this ? Did I implement something wrong? I would be very happy to have some others suggestions.

Thank you in advance.